# Virt-Manager: Using non-usb camera from host in guest system

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, libvirt, virt-manager

So I'm using droidcam (phone as webcam over WiFi) and want to use it in my guest OS as well. I found some guides on how to simply add new hardware -> usb host device and selecting the connected usb webcam.

However, my camera isn't connected via USB and I really don't know what to do or what to search for in order to make this work.

I'm using virt mngr and android-x86-9.0, it runs all fine but has no camera..
My host is debian bookworm/sid x86_64bit